# Warnings during pip installs because of a package called "-etuptools"

Tags: python, pip

A simple problem. When I install or upgrade packages with pip, I get a very weird error. Input:

```
pip3 install numpy
```

output:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -etuptools (/home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -etuptools (/home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.20.2)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -etuptools (/home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -etuptools (/home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -etuptools (/home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages)
```

Any ideas what happened?

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Python: 3.8.5

setupools: 56.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your site-packages folder (in your case: /home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages) and delete folders with "~".

You will find there
~etuptools

[Answer was found here.](https://www.programmersought.com/article/34628456120/)

[Explanation what are those folders here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64939049/441814)

Comment: Yes, thanks, I already did that as you see below.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like numpy has already installed successfully. have you tried accessing it with something like:

```
python3
>>> import numpy
>>> a=numpy.zeros(10,numpy.uint8,"C")
>>> a
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8)
>>>
```

Comment: I know that numpy is installed, and it works. The problem is that these warnings always occur once I do something with pip and I do not know how to get rid of them.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood

Comment: is there anything strange in /home/max/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages ? etuptools related.  my setuptools are in the /usr/lib//python3/dist-packages, just wondering if something has ended up with an odd name in your local user packages

Comment: Yes, there were folders named ~etuptools and ~etuptools<some_number>. I have no idea how they ended up there. Deleted them manually and the warnings are gone for now. Thanks!